# How to send AWS MWAA cluster metrics to DataDog?

Tags: airflow, metrics, datadog, mwaa

AWS's Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA) provides [cluster metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/accessing-metrics-cw-container-queue-db.html#container-list) like the  `CPUUtilization` and `MemoryUtilization` for the `BaseWorker`, `Scheduler` and `WebServer`. I would like to have these in DataDog so I can set usage alerts. Here's a example of what they look like in Cloudwatch:

[image: View of MWAA metrics in AWS]

However, DataDog's [official MWAA integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_mwaa/) doesn't have these metrics listed. Is there a way to directly specify the metrics and forward them to DataDog? Or, possibly, are they already being picked up but under an obscure namespace?